# 2D Tower Defense - Units stacking on top of each other

Tags: c++, logic, path-finding, flock

I'm currently implementing a 2D top down Tower Defense game. For the pathfinding I've used a Breadth-First-Search backwards from the goal. Everything works quite fine, though my units all follow the exact same line and therefore might stack on top of each other.

For units of the same time, I can of course release them one after another but if faster and slower units are mixed, the faster ones will "walk over" the slower ones and it looks quite weird.

In Fieldrunners 2 units walk around each other when the need to pass which looks quite cool, though I imagine that this is quite complex to implement.

Do you have any idea how I can solve these issues / improve my game?

Comment: Remove/Flag the used nodes from your graph and update your walk path after every movment

Comment: I don't quite understand. Do you mean use pathfinding with the units as obstacles once every frame?

Comment: Yes something like this but in a smaller graph.

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking into something known as steering behaviour. Use collision checks to determine when a unit is about to collide with something that they cannot pass through on a node that they should be able to pass through and use steering behaviour to avoid it.

This has the benefit of meaning that you don't have to constantly update and recalculate paths for all units, and so it is far more scalable.